# Programmatically change startColor of a border.xml that is used as a background in another xml?

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I have an xml file called border.xml in the drawable folder.
In this xml I have

```
<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++  BORDER  +++++++++++++++++++ -->
<item> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid
            android:id="@+id/shape_border_color" 
            android:color="@color/black" /> 
        <gradient 
            android:id="@+id/shapre_border_gradient" 
            android:startColor="@color/BurlyWood" 
            android:endColor="@color/Blue" 
            android:angle="270"
        /> 
<!-- ++++++++++++++++++++ ROUND CORNERS ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
        <corners
            android:id="@+id/shape_border_corners" 
            android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
            android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
            android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
            android:topRightRadius="7dp"
    /> 
    </shape>
</item>   

<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++  BACKGROUND ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
<item 
    android:left="5dp" 
    android:right="5dp"  
    android:top="5dp" >  
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
        <gradient 
            android:id="@+id/shape_background" 
            android:id="@+id/hr_design_background_gradient" 
            android:startColor="@color/DarkOrchid" 
            android:endColor="@color/LawnGreen" 
            android:angle="270"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

I use the above xml file as a background for a `LinearLayout` in my main.xml file using the following code

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_o2">
```

In my Main.java activity I am interested to change the border's `start and end colors` as well as the `background` and `Radius` of corners

I know how to change a background of a certain id if i am using the a TextView for example. But I am unsure of how to approach changing the Item/Shape/Gradiant values.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to define a 2nd drawable resource, called drawable/alternate_background.xml.  In this file you can code the alternate colors, radius values, etc.

Then you programatically load the alternate resource.

```
linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alternate_background);
```

FWIW, one advantage of this approach is that your view is still externalized.  Thus you can use the Eclipse layout editor to preview changes, rather than wait until runtime to see the effects of your changes.

Comment: Well, I kinda have few of these linearlayouts and i wanted to change colors and so on depends on certain app status (about three basic modes). so doing so will be a hassle. thought that having a method that updates colors would be easier.

Comment: Give this a try.  I don't think this is any harder.  The java code is a one-liner.  Besides, I do not think the component of drawable resources can be programatically changed, once they have been rendered.